# PHP Mysqli Prepared Statement - Update not updating

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Thanks in advance for everyone's help. I have an issue that has driven me crazy for hours. I've tried writing this several times using several methods with full error checking. I've tried single quotes on the field names, I've tried putting an SQL query in a variable and passing it to $db->prepare -- all to no avail. I've checked my permissions and everything looks good to me. I'm sure it's something simple but I'm bleary-eyed going over this and I'm just not seeing it.

```
$db = OpenDBConn();
    // $query  = "UPDATE agent_profiles SET ";
    // $query .= "website = ?, display_email = ?, primary_phone = ?, secondary_phone = ?, secondary_phone_type = ?, ";
    // $query .= "address_1 = ?, address_2 = ?, city = ?, state = ?, zip = ?, country = ?, description = ? ";
    // $query .= "WHERE agent_id = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE agent_profiles SET 
        website=?,
        display_email=?,
        primary_phone=?,
        secondary_phone=?,
        secondary_phone_type=?,
        address_1=?,
        address_2=?,
        city=?,
        state=?,
        zip=?,
        country=?,
        description=?
        WHERE agent_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssi', $this->website, $this->display_email, $this->primary_phone, $this->secondary_phone, $this->secondary_phone_type, $this->address_1, $this->address_2, $this->city, $this->state, $this->zip, $this->country, $this->description, $this->agent_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();
```

Even with full error reporting and modifying the code to look for $db->error, it all looks and runs clean but doesn't save to the table. Functions used here are used in other places and work fine. Any guesses?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking return values? Your code basically assuming nothing could ever go wrong. mysqli returns boolean false on failure.

Comment: I omitted any error checking for the sake of brevity but believe me, yes I have checked for errors along every step of the process. There are no errors being reported.

Comment: Do you have autocommit disabled?

Comment: bind_param is returning true.
execute is returning true.
There are no mysqli errors.

Comment: Autocommit is not disabled programmatically. But, just to be sure it wasn't something on the server end, I just tried to manually commit a transaction using this code and nada.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Is your friend, why do you always exclude him on your journeys?